# interactive line chart shows data points outside xDomain

Tags: javascript, charts, nvd3.js

I need to produce an interactive line chart of multiple series and I'm using NVD3 with interactivity turned on for that (useIntractiveGuidline). But there appears to be a problem if  `xDomain` of the chart is more narrow than the data points span. Consider an example. You have 3 data series with X points 1, 2, and 3. You chart has the X range of `[ 1.1, 4 ]`. Now, if you move you mouse arount the Y axis of the chart a bit, you'll see that -- even if you use `clipEdge` -- NVD3 is still displaying data points and a pop-up with values:

[image]

I've compiled a JSFiddle for this bug: http://jsfiddle.net/e6kwrqdw/. My JavaScript code:

```
var data = [
    {
        key: 's#1',
        values: [
            { x: 1, y: 5 },
            { x: 2, y: 7 },
            { x: 3, y: 3 }
        ]
    },
    {
        key: 's#2',
        values: [
            { x: 1, y: 4 },
            { x: 2, y: 8 },
            { x: 3, y: 4 }
        ]
    },
    {
        key: 's#3',
        values: [
            { x: 1, y: 1 },
            { x: 2, y: 2 },
            { x: 3, y: 6 }
        ]
    }

];

var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
    .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
    .tooltips(true)
    .margin({ left: 200 })
    .xDomain([ 1.1, 4 ])
    .clipEdge(true)
    .showLegend(true);

d3.select('#chart').datum(data).call(chart);
```